# Use think times in Visual Studio Web Performance Tests (not load tests)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, performance-testing, load-testing

**TL;DR**

In Visual Studio 2015, is it possible to use think times in a web performance test when running it from the context menu? (I'm not talking about load tests here)

**A little bit of context**

I created in Visual Studio 2015 a load test project and added a few complex web performance tests, which act as user session scenarios. The load test will then use these web performance tests by assigning one to each virtual user in the test.

I need to "unit test" these web performance tests to see if they work properly, but some of them do not behave well when the think times are not respected (essentially because I want the duration of the Web Performance Test to be deterministic so that my scenarios reflect an average user session).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Two ways.

1. In the "web test" section of the active `.testsettings` file there is a tick box for "Simulate think times". Open the `.testsettings` file from solution explorer. In the context (right click) menu for the active `.testsettings` file in solution explorer the "Active load and web test settings" entry will be ticked.
2. After running a web test, at the top of the web test results there is an "Edit run settings", click on this and the form that appears has a tick box for "Simulate think times". After updating these settings, click on the "Click here to run again" to run the test.